# Does the singular / plural match in "mon fonds"?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, accord, pluriel

I'm reading the poem "Le Chat" of Charles Baudelaire.

Based on [wiki](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Les_Fleurs_du_mal/1857/Le_Chat_(%C2%AB_Dans_ma_cervelle_se_prom%C3%A8ne_%C2%BB)), it says

> Cette voix, qui perle et qui filtre
> Dans mon fonds le plus ténébreux, ...

May I ask, why here *mon* shows singular, but *fonds* shows plural?

Note, *fonds* according to [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/fonds), can be singular, but only as meaning as "funds" in English.

The full poem is as below:

> LE CHAT
>
> Dans ma cervelle se promène,
> Ainsi qu’en son appartement,
> Un beau chat, fort, doux et charmant ;
> Quand il miaule, on l’entend à peine,
>
> Tant son timbre est tendre et discret ;
> Mais que sa voix s’apaise ou gronde,
> Elle est toujours suave et profonde.
> C’est là son charme et son secret.
>
> Cette voix, qui perle et qui filtre
> Dans mon fonds le plus ténébreux,
> Me remplit comme un vers nombreux
> Et me pénètre comme un philtre.
>
> Elle endort les plus cruels maux
> Et contient toutes les extases ;
> Pour dire les plus longues phrases,
> Elle n’a pas besoin de mots.
>
> Non, il n’est pas d’archet qui morde
> Sur mon cœur, parfait instrument,
> Et fasse plus royalement
> Chanter sa plus vibrante corde
>
> Que ta voix, chat mystérieux,
> Chat séraphique, chat étrange,
> En qui tout est, comme en un ange,
> Aussi subtil qu’harmonieux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, *mon* is singular, as is *le fonds* in this case. See the remarks under [*fonds*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fonds/3), *substantif masculin*. It can be singular especially in the sense of character or virtues of a person under the *figuratif* definition C.2.

> 2. Capital de qualités naturelles ou acquises, de tendances morales ou intellectuelles, bonnes ou mauvaises, propres à une personne. *Une
>    grosse figure joufflue qui trouvait le moyen d'allier un air de
>    vivacité à un grand fonds de bêtise* (JOUY, L'Hermite, t. 2, 1812, p.
>    373).

The figurative meanings, one with *s* and one without, are close enough and the etymology is identical.  The financial sense is the same root, think "fundamental." Since so many writers mixed them up or used fonds with or without *s* arbitrarily, there is a recommendation to do away with the *s* and end the confusion, but context is key.  Baudelaire clearly refers to how his own personal depth or depths respond to the sound of the *chat*.

> Rem. ,,On peut voir à l'étymologie que *fonds* et *fond* sont exactement
> le même mot. Aussi quand *fonds* est pris comme ce qu'une personne a de
> savoir, d'esprit, de probité, etc. et *fond* comme ce qui fait une sorte
> de fondement et d'état permanent, les deux significations se
> confondent tellement que les orthographes dans les auteurs varient
> sans cesse, et qu'on pourrait faire passer plusieurs exemples sans
> difficulté de *fonds* à *fond*, ou de *fond* à *fonds*. Le mieux serait de
> supprimer l'*s* de *fonds*, et de ne faire qu'un seul mot de ce qui n'en
> est réellement qu'un, répondant en latin au mot unique *fundus*``
> (LITTRÉ). Cf. aussi DUPRÉ 1972, pp. 1032-1033. V. fond III C 2.